# Usng JSON in codeigniter with form submit

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

Im trying to learn how to use JSON from within codeigniter.  I'm trying to use a model to run the ajax code, but its not working.

I need to learn how to pass variables through to the model, and back out; or, if thats incorrect, I need to learn the correct process. The below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="structures">
    <h1>Build</h1>
    <form name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST">
        <select name="buildID" class="buildClass">
        <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Build a Structure</option>
    <option name='Town Center' value='1' data-icon='../img/structures/tc.png' data-html-text='Town Center<i>
        500 minutes<br>50000 gold</i>'>Town Center</option>
    <option name='Barracks' value='2' data-icon='../img/structures/barracks.png' data-html-text='Barracks<i>
        25 minutes<br>1500 gold</i>'>Barracks</option>
    <option name='Dragon Roost' value='3' data-icon='../img/structures/droost.png' data-html-text='Dragon Roost<i>
        200 minutes<br>5000 gold</i>'>Dragon Roost</option>
    <option name='Mage Hall' value='4' data-icon='../img/structures/mage.png' data-html-text='Mage Hall<i>
        40 minutes<br>300 gold</i>'>Mage Hall</option>
    <option name='Test Lab' value='6' data-icon='../img/structures/testlab.png' data-html-text='Test Lab<i>
        1 minutes<br>10 gold</i>'>Test Lab</option>
        </select>
        <div id="buildSubmit">
            <input id ="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Here is my ajax/js/json**
I'm trying a very simple example.  I'd like to post the value of the OPTION above (1-6) to the model function insert_build.  I don't know if its doing it, as I can't really think of a good way to test it.  However, I would assume if it returned anything, I would be alerted.  I am not.

```
$(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(e, value){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php $this->structure_model->insert_build() ?>",         //the script to call to get data          
        str_id: value,
        dataType: 'json',                //data format      
        success: function(data)          //on receive of reply
            {
                alert("success!");
            } 
        });
 });
});
```

**The model code**

```
 public function insert_build()
        {
            $str_id = $this->input->post('str_id');
            echo " TESTING $str_id";
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Why doesn't this work?  I am still trying to understand the fundamentals of Codeigniter and JSON / JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url:` you're setting in your javascript is the actual function you're wanting to call when the ajax is submitted.  You'll need to have a controller in place that actually calls that function e.g.

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/structure/insert/?str_id=" + $('#buildID').val(),
```

Also, setting `dataType:` to `json` means you're expecting what's returned from your function to be encoded as json.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to do this without requiring the javascript to be directly on the page source?

Comment: You can set the base_url in a javascript variable and then just include a js file that has the ajax code. `var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';` then change your ajax `url` to use the new `base_url` variable

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  However, while I was able to receive a response and an alert, "TESTING" it is not returning the variable "str_id"  Would you be able to edit your answer to include that reasoning? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change this:

```
 url: "<?php echo $this->structure_model->insert_build() ?>"
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything if you look at all of the example code.